# Call Windows service method from WEB Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have created Windows service and installed on my PC, and added one method in that. For example:

```
Public int Add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
```

Now I want to call this method which is present in "MyService", and there is one web application hosted on IIS server, from this application on button click event I want to call this method. (Actually this is a project requirement.)

I think we can use reflection for this, I tried a lot but didn't get actual solution for this.

Detail Requirement : 
1) One Web Application hosted on IIS server. 
2) Other users lets say there are 50 users accessing this web application from their own PC.
3) One Windows service is hosted on this all 50 PC's.
4) If any one user clicks on "Execute W" button, then It should call the windows service of his PC( not IIS server) by passing required parameters.

Comment: You could expose your Windows Service as an WCF service and use IPC binding to comunicate with it.

Comment: win service is working permanently. you can communicate with win service through sql database for example.

Comment: @Oscar : Can you please explain in detail ? , Is there any way other than this ( I dont want to use database.)

Comment: @isxaker : I cant use database here, any other way?

Comment: Detail Requirment : 1)  One Web Application hosted on IIS server.  2) Other users lets say there are 50 users accessing this web application from their own PC.3) One Windows service is hosted on this all 50 PC's 4) If any one user clicks on "Execute W" button, then It should call the windows service of his PC( not IIS server) by passing required parameters . Please suggest

Comment: win service usually is sort of independent application. So that you should use some shared data for communicatiog between win service and your web app.

Comment: @Mangesh, forget it, IPC I only work for process in the same computer. But the windows service can expose a wcf service that you can communicate to trough your web with an HTTP binding. However, your questions is too broad and your architecture doesn't seems to be well engineered. It looks weird having a website talking to a windows service on the client machine...

Comment: @Oscar, but unfortunately, this is a requirnment, Can we call windows service method through reflection.